# How to make puppeteer run headless with the apify sdk?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sdk, apify

I am trying to scrape the content of a page using the apify sdk.
This also works nicely with the following code. But how can I force using the Apify SDK the headless mode as with puppeteer.launch({headless: true})?

Code for your reference:

```
async function scrape(number) {
  let output = { links: [], title: [], content: [] };
  const URL = "https://somepage/";
  process.env.APIFY_LOCAL_STORAGE_DIR = '/someappfolder/apify_storage/run_' + number;

  const requestQueue = await Apify.openRequestQueue(number);
  await requestQueue.addRequest({ url: URL });
  const pseudoUrls = [new Apify.PseudoUrl(URL + "[.*]")];
  const crawler = new Apify.PuppeteerCrawler({
    requestQueue,
    handlePageFunction: async ({ request, page }) => {

      output.links.push(request.url);
      output.title.push(await page.title());
      output.content.push((await page.content()).length);
      var save = { url: request.url, title: await page.title(), content: (await page.content()).length };
      //sendToAirtable(save);

      console.log(`URL: ${request.url}`);
      await Apify.utils.enqueueLinks({
        page,
        selector: 'a',
        pseudoUrls,
        requestQueue,
      });
    },
    maxRequestsPerCrawl: 10,
    maxConcurrency: 10,
    minConcurrency: 2,
  });

  await crawler.run();
  return output;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

*Add `launchPuppeteerOptions: { headless: true }` on the same level as `requestQueue`
https://sdk.apify.com/docs/typedefs/launch-puppeteer-options#docsNav*

EDIT: This no longer works. Latest docs are https://crawlee.dev/api/browser-crawler/interface/BrowserLaunchContext#launchOptions

Comment: This doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Yeah, this was for old version

Answer (score 0):

`process.env.APIFY_HEADLESS = 1;`

Is the answer upon I stumbled after hours of searching...
https://sdk.apify.com/docs/guides/environment-variables#apify_headless

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the in-code answers here would work. I had to google this, and this seems to work.

```
const Apify = require('apify');

Apify.main(async () => {
    const baseurl = 'https://thedomain.youwanna.check.com/somepage';

    const requestQueue = await Apify.openRequestQueue();
    await requestQueue.addRequest({ url: baseurl });

    const options = {
        requestQueue,
        launchContext: {
            launchOptions: {
                headless: true,
                slowMos: 1000,
            }
        },
        handlePageFunction: async ({ request, page }) => {
            const title = await page.title();
            console.log(`Title of ${request.url}: ${title}`);
            request
            await Apify.utils.enqueueLinks({
               requestQueue,
               page,
               pseudoUrls: [baseurl + '[.*]'],
            });
        },
    };
    const crawler = new Apify.PuppeteerCrawler(options);
    await crawler.run();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add the headless option to the `launchPuppeteerOptions` like this:

```
const crawler = new Apify.PuppeteerCrawler({
            requestQueue,
            launchPuppeteerOptions: {
                headless: true,
                ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
                // slowMo: 500,
            },
            maxRequestsPerCrawl: settings.maxurls,
            maxConcurrency: settings.maxcrawlers,
```